# Passing an object as Meta/Tag when extending a class. What is this syntax and what does it do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I just started my first react-native project and stumbled across a weird syntax, that i did not see so far (at least in javascript context).

Does this come from react, react-native or ecma6? And more important: What does it specify:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    // class code
}
```

I am confused about this part: **<{}>**

The tokens < and > make me assume that has to do with react, but i might be wrong, since i kind of remember seeing this in other languages before.

Please enlighten me :-)

Comment: Are you using TypeScript or something ? This looks like a generic https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: No, that code was generated by react-native when initializing the project.

Comment: Do you have a link to your boilerplate or starter project ? This syntax is not ES6 or react native

Comment: Here you can see the template, as it will be copied to your new project:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/90eaeb019b2056150cae541a59720daad21466ef/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/App.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of static analysis!

The syntax you are seeing is that of [flow](https://flow.org). Flow is a static analysis tool which provides types for javascript. Javascript is a **weakly typed** language. That means you can do this below without any issues.

```js
let name = 'Kyle';
name = 4; // We just assigned a number to a string
```

Because Javascript doesn't complain about this, it means this could cause some problems for us later - especially if we expect `name` to be a string.

Flow comes to the rescue at this point and allows us to use types in our javascript code. Let's change our example to use flow. This time we explicitly say that name will be a string.

```js
let name: string = 'Kyle'
```

Now when we try to assign a value that isn't a string, flow will give us a warning;

```js
name = 4;
```

[image]

Great! Flow now protects us from variables having wrong information.

Let's see how this fits in with react native.

If you've created a new react native project, you've likely seen a comment at the top of your file that looks like this.

```js
// @flow
```

This is a marker that tells flow, check this file for errors. In react native our components have Props and State. In the example code you posted - it tells flow that your Props are an object that can contain any key. That's not very useful, so let's look at an example that uses types.

Imagine we have a component that just renders names.

```js
class NamePrinter extends React.Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
  }
}
```

Now let's add some flow typing to it.

```js
type NamePrinterProps = {
  name: string;
}

// Change our example to use the typing

class NamePrinter extends React.Component<NamePrinterProps>
```

Now when we use the NamePrinter component and name isn't a string, flow will give us a nice error.

```js
class App extends React.Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return <NamePrinter name={4}/>
  }
}
```

[image]

Congratulations! You've now used static typing in your javascript project! Flow is one of many static analysis tools. You can also checkout Typescript which does this and more.

Flow - https://flow.org/en/

Typescript - https://www.typescriptlang.org